# Solution Verification: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(n!)^2}{(2n)!}$ using ratio test

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, solution-verification

I don't have the 'official' solution to this series so I wanted to verify the one I came up with. I checked if this post is a duplicate but have not found one which includes the use of Ratio test.
\begin{equation*}
(s_n)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(n!)^2}{(2n)!}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n!\cdot n!}{(2n)!}
\end{equation*}
$\underline{\text{Claim:}}$ $(s_n)$ converges (absolutely).

$\underline{\text{Proof:}}$ Using ratio test:
\begin{equation*}
\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|=\left|\frac{\frac{(n+1)!(n+1)!}{(2(n+1))!}}{\frac{n!\cdot n!}{(2n)!}}\right|=\frac{\frac{(n+1)!(n+1)!}{(2(n+1))!}}{\frac{n!\cdot n!}{(2n)!}}=\frac{(n+1)!(n+1)!}{(2(n+1))!}\cdot\frac{(2n)!}{n!\cdot n!}=\frac{(n+1)!(n+1)!(2n)!}{n!\cdot n!\cdot(2n+2)!}
\end{equation*}
Further:
\begin{equation*}
\frac{(n+1)!(n+1)!(2n)!}{n!\cdot n!\cdot(2n+2)!}=\frac{(n+1)^2(2n)!}{(2n+2)!}=\frac{(n+1)^2(2n)!}{(2n)!\cdot(2n+1)\cdot(2n+2)}=\frac{(n+1)^2}{(2n+1)(2n+2)}=\frac{n^2+2n+1}{4n^2+6n+2}.
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\frac{n^2+2n+1}{4n^2+6n+2}=\frac{n^2\cdot(1+\frac{2}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2})}{n^2\cdot(4+\frac{6}{n}+\frac{2}{n^2})}=\frac{1+\frac{2}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2}}{4+\frac{6}{n}+\frac{2}{n^2}}\rightarrow\frac{1+0+0}{4+0+0}=\frac{1}{4}=\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|.
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
C=\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|=\frac{1}{3}
\end{equation*}
Since $C=\frac{1}{3}<1$: $(s_n)$ converges absolutely.

Comment: If the limit of the ratio exists, it is enough to compute that and check that it is strictly less than $1$. No need to deal with liminf and limsup since they are the same.

Comment: where did the $1/3$ come from? It looks like you showed $C=1/4$.

Comment: $\lim{a_{n+1}/a_n}=1/4$ so the limit sup and the limit inf are equal ; anyway it's enough to prove absolute convergence of the series

Comment: I belive $1/3$ is the $\sup$.

Comment: $\limsup$ is not the same as $\sup$ and here they are $\frac14$ and $\frac13$.  Either works here